# Changing the search URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, search

I want to change the search URL from `example.com/search/keyword` to `example.com/result` or `topic/keyword`.

Comment: By `/result`, do you mean you always use the URL `/result`, for any search term, or is `result` just a placeholder and do you want a search for `banana` to end up at `domain.com/banana`?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `/search/` part to something else, like `/topic/`, but it will be harder to remove it completely, since that will conflict with WordPress Pages (is `/banana/` a Page with the title "Banana" or is it the result page for the search term "Banana"?).

To change the part, hook into the `init` action and change the `$wp_rewrite->search_base` variable:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse21549_init' );
function wpse21549_init()
{
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->search_base = 'topic';
}
```

You will need to place this snippet of code in your theme's `function.php` file, or in a new file that you create and that you place in the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory. After you did this, visit the *Permalinks* setting page to flush the rewrite rules.

However, by default when you submit a search you will end up on a URL like `?s=Banana`. There are plugins that change this (Ramukar linked to one, but it has the `/search/` part hardcoded and has other issues), and Hudson Atwell linked to a simple approach (even too complicated now: you don't need to add the rewrite rule to Apache, as WordPress already contained them since version 1.5).

Answer (score -1):

Just install this plugin, [Search Permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-permalink/).that's it.you got answer.:)

Comment: That plugin will change `?s=keyword` to `/search/keyword`, it will not change the `search` part (it's even hardcoded, so you won't be able to change it to something else).